# Design Issue - Creating aspx pages dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I currently have a web application that serves a single dashboard page. The client would like multiple dashboards for different systems displayed on the same physical machine.  They would like to avoid installing many instances of the application as this would require opening up too many ports to view different dashboards.

They have suggested I alter my application to include multiple tabs/pages for each dashboard. Currently I have some C# classes which gather and process the data and feed it into the Default.aspx.cs file which then uses Web HTML controls to generate the html content and feed it into Default.aspx page via a placeholder.

At runtime I don't know how many Dashboards there will be or what they will be called (the C# classes read information from textfiles located in each dashboard directory on the drive, C:\Dashboard1*.txt C:\Dashboard2*.txt).

I am new to this and I'm struggling to see how to split the design out so that I can dynamically create the aspx.cs file and aspx file for each dashboard object.

Would a solution be to create a Dashboard.cs class that handles all the html generation (in place of default.aspx.cs) and creates an aspx page dynamically for each dashboard found on C:. Would all of the Web HTMLControls still work without a link between an aspx.cs file and a aspx file?

I realise this question is vague...**more specifically I guess I am asking:**

How do I create an aspx page dynamically from a C# class and then add web html controls to it?  E.g. create the aspx page from a template and then use controls like `HTMLGenericControl RowDiv = new HTMLGenericControl('div')`.  I wouldn't know how to link my C# class to the newly created aspx page so that the HTML Web controls knew they were supposed to be added to that new aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the dashboard as an user control, and add the controls you need dynamically. Doing it like this you also have the option to create different looking dashboards (if you need it).